# Is there an order to how unique constraint violations occur in oracle sql?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, unique-constraint

Given that we have a table like this,

table name: my_table; 
columns: id, a, b, c; 
primary key: id; 
 
unique constraints: a, (b, c);

I want to know whether there is an ordering to how the unique constraints would fail.

With this setting, I do the following insert 
`insert into my_table values (1,2,3,4);`

And then I do the same insert once more. Can I be sure that this second insert will fail because of the primary key violation, and not because of the unique key constraints on the other columns?

And then, if I try to do this `insert into my_table values (2,2,3,4);`, is there a way for me to make sure which unique constraint would fail first (the one on column `a` or the one on columns `(b,c)`)?

Comment: Try it; when creating constraints, give them meaningful names. Then do your inserts and watch what Oracle says.

Comment: I actually did try it and what I want to know is that if I can expect the same ordering in all such cases (as in if there's a predictable ordering). 
I am trying to use this in a pl/sql package and based on the `DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX` exception, I'm trying to return the existing row of the table. So I was hoping if there's a predictable ordering as to how unique constraints are violated, I could use a `select` based on the violated columns to find the existing entry for the table.

Comment: This guy talks about it https://hourim.wordpress.com/2014/07/30/on-table-constraint-execution-order/

Comment: I see; well, I have no idea (very useful, eh?). I know that - if there are several triggers of the same type declared on the same table - there's no specific order they are going to fire on. *Maybe* the same goes for those constraints of yours ...

Comment: The real question is: why do you care? What is the underlying problem you are trying to solve with that information?

Comment: If you're catching that exception the `SQLERRM` tells you which constraint was violated; you'd have to parse it out, but still, doesn't that give you what you need?

Comment: Use case: I can have a table - asset, that have to have unique name and a unique code. I can create 2 unique non-clustered constraint u_asset_name & u_asset_code. When adding a row, depending on the violation I can provide a more meaningful error. However, if the sequence is reversed the error becomes meaningless...